# Identifying 2-Pin Connector for Cooling Fan in Head Unit

Tags: connector

I am replacing a cooling fan on a factory head unit/radio that was originally in a Chevrolet truck, circa 2002.

The original cooling fan is a Delta Electronics AFB0412MA.

[image]

I will be replacing it with a Delta Electronics AFB0412MA-A. My understanding of the [AFB0412MA-A datasheet](https://www.delta-fan.com/Download/Spec/AFB0412MA-A.pdf) is that the two leads of the AFB0412MA-A do not terminate in a connector, but rather, just two wire leads.

[image]

I was able to remove the connector from the old fan, and I plan to re-use it on the new fan. So at this point, all I need is to identify the connector make/model, and in doing so, I can identify what terminals it accepts.

Here is what I know about the connector:

- It is white.
- It has two circuits (pins) and two cavities.
- My estimation of the terminal pitch, measured with a caliper, is **2.0 mm**.
- It has MSH29 printed on it.
- The circuit board header that the connectors connects into has MSH11 printed on it.

[image]

The connector is 6 mm long, 6 mm wide on the side that the wires enter, and 5 mm wide at the opposite side (although not rectangular-shaped).

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Any ideas what make/model connector this is?

Comment: Looks JST-ish; have you scanned their catalogs?

Comment: @Hearth—Yeah, I have, a couple of times. That was my first thought as well. That or Molex. Still have not found one that is identical. I'll have to give the catalogs a review.

Comment: If you've already scanned JST and Molex, TE/AMP might be another place to look, though I don't know that I've seen this style of connector from them very often.

Comment: Did you try de-soldering the male connector from the PCB so that you can put any other 2-pin connector with the same pitch?

Comment: @Nithin-Will do, as a last resort though.

Comment: The easy way is to cut the wires and solder them to the new fan's wires.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [Molex Microblade](https://tools.molex.com/pdm_docs/sd/530140210_sd.pdf) connector.

[image]
([image source](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/molex/0530140210/1785063))

It appears they are no longer manufactured; Digikey lists the [entire series](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors/headers-male-pins/314?s=N4IgjCBcoLQCxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAG4B2aWehA9lANogBsAHAEwAMIAuoQA4AuUECAC%20ooA) as obsolete, and Molex's website has no mention of them. The series seems to have been replaced with the Picoblade series, but they're not compatible; Picoblade has a 1.25 mm pitch.

So your best bet is to either splice the existing connector onto the new fan, or replace the connector entirely. It appears to just be an ordinary 2.0 mm pitch connector, so you can probably replace it with a JST PA/PH or a Molex Micro-clasp or something.

Comment: Thank you! Appears the female connector is Molex 51004-0200 and [female] terminals are Molex 50011-8000. Looks like terminals are still sourceable. Thanks again!